# Why cannot I chmod in Cygwin on Windows 8 CP?

Tags: windows-8, cygwin

I can't chmod group permission in Cygwin on Windows 8 so that I can't ssh connect to a server using an ssh key.

Bash prompt warning: "Permissions 0660 for '/home/KeepZero/.ssh/id_rsa' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others."

```
KeepZero@t400win8 ~
$ ls
test

KeepZero@t400win8 ~
$ ls -l
total 0
-rwxrwx--- 1 KeepZero KeepZero 0 Mar  4 15:07 test

KeepZero@t400win8 ~
$ chmod 700 test

KeepZero@t400win8 ~
$ ls -l test
-rwxrwx--- 1 KeepZero KeepZero 0 Mar  4 15:07 test

KeepZero@t400win8 ~
$ chmod 777 test

KeepZero@t400win8 ~
$ ls -l test
-rwxrwxrwx 1 KeepZero KeepZero 0 Mar  4 15:07 test
```

Comment: Works for me. What sort of filesystem are you using there?

Comment: Ah, I'd overlooked that it's on Windows 8, so forget my comment. Best to report this to the Cygwin mailing list I think.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Do an `ls -al` and you will see that your files do not belong to any group (none).

Just do a `chgrp Users *` on your files, and you are fine again.

Comment: Yes and remember to do your `chmod 600 <file>` afterwards

Comment: I just found this in a Google search. How does this affect creation of files outside of Cygwin? So if, for instance, I `chgrp Users * ~` and then I want to edit a file by opening it through Explorer in Notepad? Does this still work normally? And if so, is there a document saying why they don't do this by default in the first place?

Comment: This answer doesn't solve the inital problem and it will do this bug every time you create a new file. The second answer solves the problem.

Comment: As an aside, you might need to translate "Users" in the command. For example, my French Windows is expecting "chgrp Utilisateurs *".

Comment: The list of groups is available in `/etc/group`. Pick one of them.

Answer (score 48):

[Roi Danton's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561759/why-cannot-i-chmod-in-cygwin-on-windows-8-cp/10190868#10190868) works, however it does not solve the root cause, and the issue will recur with any user-created file on which you want to change the permissions.

To fix the problem permanently:

1. Look up the group ID of the "Users" group in `/etc/group` (or the equivalent group name for your locale).

   In my installation this was 545 (your mileage may vary).
   `cat /etc/group|egrep '^Users:'` will get you the correct line. The third field on the line is the group id.  (`cat /etc/group|egrep '^Users:'|cut -f3 -d':'` to just get the id).
2. Edit your `/etc/passwd` file. Locate the record for your user. The fourth field is the "primary group" for the user. It is incorrectly set to a non-existent group. Change that number to the number you found in step 1 above. Save the `etc` password file.
3. Close any open Cygwin windows/terminals and then open a new one. Create a new file. It should have a group of "Users", and you should be able to change its permissions as desired.

Comment: This answer should be accepted as it solves the initial problem and is not a little fix. Please note that the name of the group depends from the lang of the user machine. In my case, it was "Utilisateurs" (in French).

Comment: $ cat /etc/group|egrep '^Usuarios:'|cut -f3 -d':' for Spanish users.

Comment: This solution is the first I've found that allows me to chown -R myuser:myuser  /usr/share/zsh

Answer (score 1):

A possible reason of this problem is that you have copied your .ssh folder on the actual pc...

Create your own folder, and then you get the right user group. Don't copy folders... they are assigned to user groups that don't match.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on [Windows Server 2012](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2012) R2. After trying to change the owner or group or even the permissions of a file it still showed the original values and ignored my settings.

After reading *[File permissions](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ntsec.html#ntsec-files)*,

> **File permissions**
>
> On NTFS and if the noacl mount option is not specified for a mount
> point, Cygwin sets file permissions as on POSIX systems.

I figured out that the *noacl* option was set for the mountpoins:

```
$ mount
C:/cygwin/bin on /usr/bin type ntfs (binary,noacl)
C:/cygwin/lib on /usr/lib type ntfs (binary,noacl)
C:/cygwin on / type ntfs (binary,noacl)
C: on /cygdrive/c type ntfs (binary,posix=0,user,noumount,noacl,auto)
```

So I removed the *noacl* option from the mountpoints in `/etc/fstab` and closed all Cygwin windows. After reopening the console the permission setting with chown, chgrp, and chmod worked as expected.

Comment: I see `noacl` in the output of `mount` but not in `/etc/fstab`.  Could you please show what you have in your `/etc/fstab` now?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue in Windows 10 in the Cygwin command prompt.

For the id file, only the root user should have full permission and for other users restricted/no permissions should be fine.

The below command solves the issue,

```
 chmod 700 <id-file>
```